# Global navigation header - subpage clicks not working off of subpages

Tags: css, url, href

I've been working with github pages to run my website. I am currently trying to develop a global header that can be adjusted in one js file and reflect everywhere. The problem is, I have url link problems when going to subpages when running off of another subpage. I want to be able to call the one js file, and have the links work ***no matter what the root is***.

My html header code:

```
<!--Set the div for the header bar. Import a js file that runs a specific script to set a universal header amongst all the pages.-->
    <div id="header-bar"></div>
<!--Please note, on subpages the entered src is ../javascript/header-bar.js to adjust to location.-->
    <script src="javascript/header-bar.js"></script>
```

The js header-bar code:

```
var headerbar = document.getElementById("header-bar");
//This sets each page/subpage to be the exact same header.
headerbar.innerHTML = '<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Games</button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="universes/index.html">Universe Generator</a><a href="#">Coming soon...</a></div><div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Tools</button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="nameGenerator/index.html">Name Generator</a><a href="#">Coming soon...</a></div></div>';
```

What I believe is occurring is I am linking myself to `"nameGenerator/nameGenerator/index.html"` instead of `"nameGenerator/index.html"` whenever on one of these subpages.

---

Here is a running snippet of my code:

```js
var headerbar = document.getElementById("header-bar");

headerbar.innerHTML = '<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Games</button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="universes/index.html">Universe Generator</a><a href="#">Coming soon...</a></div></div><div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Tools</button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="nameGenerator/index.html">Name Generator</a><a href="#">Coming soon...</a></div></div>';
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
  min-width: 160px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#header-bar {
 background-color: #509b53;
}
#header-bar:hover {
 background-color: #66ba69;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css"/>
 </head>
    <body>
  
  <!--Set the div for the header bar. Import a js file that runs a specific script to set a universal header amongst all the pages.-->
  <div id="header-bar"></div>
  <script src="javascript/header-bar.js"></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

---

How am I able to setup the href's so that no matter what page or subpage I am on the links will work correctly? I want to have the system be **fully** automated, with no need to change roots for each subpage/page. My guess is I need to have a special root symbol in front of each url, but after a hour of stackoverflow & google I can't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Side note: I can't just put the whole local url file, as when I import to github I'd have to change it all over from the local url to the github url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your href:

```
href="../universes/index.html"
```

This goes up one level (the root folder) and gets to -> universes -> index.html

**Updated**

Based on further comments from you, here is a workable solution:

```
var href = document.location.href;
var current_dir = href.substr(0, href.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

This should works in any directory:

```
headerbar.innerHTML = '<a href="'+current_dir+'/index.html">Universe Generator</a>
```

Comment: This works on a subpage, but doesn't work on the main page. I want to be able to run the same header code no matter what the page is. This will only ever work when its on the first subpage. It won't work on the master/main page or on a second/third subpage.

Comment: It is the same principle. You basically need to know where the current page relative to the root directory. This is based on what you posted, I don't know how your rest of code structured.

Comment: What I'm doing is on each page I call the same header-bar.js file. This than plants the header html the same way on each page. I would like it to be automated so I don't need to change every single page to accomodate for a different route.

Comment: Maybe something from `document.location` able to help you to figure this out. Just console.log and take a look at each case, and see how the structure your uri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141310/discussion-between-hcheung-and-bdkopen).